# Details of Shouryya Ray's Solution

Tags: fluid-dynamics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Teenager solves Newton dynamics problem - where is the paper?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150242/teenager-solves-newton-dynamics-problem-where-is-the-paper)

Duplicate question.  Please answer here instead: [Teenager solves Newton dynamics problem - where is the paper?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/150242/23003)

I came across some news stories regarding Shouryya Ray, a 16-year old German boy of Indian origin who has apparently solved a problem posed by Newton.

Unfortunately the mainstream press don't seem to have provided any details on either the problem or the solution, and I haven't been able to track this down.

Does anyone have any further information on this?  If you have the actual paper, which I think is in German, that would be excellent.  Even more excellent if you translate it to English!

Some articles:

http://www.heraldsun.com.au/news/more-news/german-teen-shouryya-ray-solves-300-year-old-mathematical-riddle-posed-by-sir-isaac-newton/story-e6frf7lf-1226368935357

The German website for the competition he entered:
http://www.jufo-dresden.de/projekt/teilnehmer/matheinfo/m1

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/150419/5363 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28931/587

Comment: I foresee many a duplicate.

Comment: Ahh OK.  Yes, this is a duplicate. My apologies.